# Merging a pandas groupby result back into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this...

```
   idn value  
0  ID1    25
1  ID1    30
2  ID2    30
3  ID2    50
```

I want to add another column to this frame that is the max 'value' grouped by 'idn'

I want a result that looks like this.

```
   idn value  max_val
0  ID1    25       30
1  ID1    30       30
2  ID2    30       50
3  ID2    50       50
```

I can extract the max of 'value' using a group by like so...

```
df[['idn', 'value']].groupby('idn')['value'].max()
```

However, I am unable to merge that result back into the original DataFrame.

What is the best way to get the desired result?

Thank You

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the `transform` method on a groupby object:

```
In [5]: df['maxval'] = df.groupby(by=['idn']).transform('max')

In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   idn  value  maxval
0  ID1     25      30
1  ID1     30      30
2  ID2     30      50
3  ID2     50      50
```

Comment: `.transform('max')` is also a shortcut to this :)

Comment: @AndyHayden `lambda c: print('i like lambdas')` :)

Answer (score 2):

set the index of `df` to `idn`, and then use `df.merge`. after the merge, reset the index and rename columns

```
dfmax = df.groupby('idn')['value'].max()

df.set_index('idn', inplace=True)

df = df.merge(dfmax, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)

df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df.columns = ['idn', 'value', 'max_value']
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that is interested. The one-liner method for this is to use reset_index.

as such:

```
df['value_max'] = df[['idn', 'value']].groupby('idn')['value'].max().reset_index(['idn', 'value'], drop = True)
```

Comment: This will not work. `(...).reset_index(['idn', 'value'], drop=True)` will return an error, as 'value' is not a level of the index.

Also, resetting the index doesn't get the old index, it creates a new one. You could do this via something like `df['max'] = df.groupby('idn')['value'].max().reindex(df['idn']).set_axis(df.index)`, but I'm not sure why you'd want to do this over either transform or even setting 'idn' as the index in the first place.